# efeito com jQuery no select

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Bom estou montando um input personalizado com o estilo do material design do google.

O efeito esta funcionando no input, porém no select não esta dando certo. Alguém sabe o que estou fazendo errado?

OBS: O efeito a qual eu me refiro é o da linha azul que fica em baixo do select.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Efeito do label
  $('.form_campos').on('focus blur', function(e) {
    $(this).parents('.form-group').toggleClass('focused', (e.type === 'focus' || this.value.length > 0));
    $(this).parents('.form-group').toggleClass('animate', (e.type === 'focus'));
  }).trigger('blur');
  $('.select').on('change blur', function(e) {
    $(this).parents('.form-group-select').toggleClass('focused', (e.type === 'focus' || this.value !== ''));
  }).trigger('blur');

  // Auto focus
  $(".autofocus").trigger('focus');

  // Verifica se o input esta disabilitado
  $('input:disabled').addClass('form_disabled');

  // Verifica se o select esta disabilitado
  $('select:disabled').addClass('select_disabled');

  // Converte minusculas em maiusculas
  $('input').not('[name="link"]').on('input', function() {

    // Armazena posição corrente do cursor
    var start = this.selectionStart,
      end = this.selectionEnd;
    this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();

    // Restaura posição armazenada anteriormente.
    this.setSelectionRange(start, end);
  });
});
```

```css
/* Input */

.form-group {
  margin-top: 20px;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  height: 45px;
  float: left;
}

.form-group::after {
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: #0091FF;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  content: '';
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: ease-in-out 240ms all;
}

.form-group.animate::after {
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

.control-label {
  opacity: 0.4;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate3d(5px, 22px, 0) scale(1);
  transform-origin: left top;
  transition: 240ms;
}

.form-group.focused .control-label,
.form-group-select.focused .control-label {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(0.75);
}

.form_campos {
  height: 31px;
  width: 100%;
  color: #484848;
  align-self: flex-end;
  padding: 5px;
  outline: none;
  border: 0 solid #484848;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  background: transparent;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.form_campos:hover,
.form_campos:focus {
  border-color: #0091FF;
}

.form_disabled,
.form_disabled:hover,
.form_disabled:focus {
  border-color: #D7D7D7;
}


/* Select */

.select {
  height: 31px;
  color: #484848;
  border-radius: 0;
  border: 0 solid #484848;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  margin-top: 14px;
  background: transparent;
  padding-right: 20px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.select::after {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background: #0091FF;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  content: '';
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: ease-in-out 240ms all;
}

select::-ms-expand {
  display: none;
}

.select:hover,
.select:focus {
  border: 0 solid;
  border-bottom-width: 2px;
  border-color: #0091FF;
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

.form-group-select {
  margin-top: 20px;
  position: relative;
  height: 45px;
  float: left;
}

.form-group-select:after {
  content: "\279C";
  color: #484848;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  right: 8px;
  top: 22px;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.select_disabled,
.select_disabled:hover,
.select_disabled:focus {
  border: 0 solid;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  border-color: #D7D7D7;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='form-group'>
  <label class='control-label' for='nome'>NOME</label>
  <input type='text' class='form_campos' id='nome' name='nome'>
</div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div class='form-group-select'>
  <label class='control-label'>GOSTOU?</label>
  <select name='gostou' class='select form_campos'>
                    <option value="s">SIM xxxxxxxxxxxxxx</option>  
                    <option value="n">NÃO xxxxxxxxxxxxxx</option>
                </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No código jQuery troque `change` por `focus` para haver correspondência com a validação da função `toggleClass()`. Além disto adicione mais uma linha dentro da função `select` para setar a animação. Ficando dessa forma a função:

```
  $('.select').on('focus blur', function(e) {
    $(this).parents('.form-group-select').toggleClass('focused', (e.type === 'focus' || this.value !== ''));
    $(this).parents('.form-group-select').toggleClass('animate', (e.type === 'focus'));
```

Já no CSS:

**Adicione**:

```
.form-group-select.animate::after {
  transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

**Altere:**

```
.select::after {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background: #0091FF;
  position: absolute;
}

.select:hover,
.select:focus {
  border: 0 solid;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  border-color: #0091FF;
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

.form-group-select:after {
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background: #0091FF;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    content: '';
    transform: scaleX(0);
    transition: ease-in-out 240ms all;
}
```

A animação ocorre no nível da div (`<div class='form-group-select'>`) e não do select, por isto as alterações em ambas as classes. Já em `.select:hover,.select:focus` você deve diminuir a largura da borda para 1px para que a borda não aumente de tamanho quando "focada".

Veja a [**DEMO**](https://lucasnovaes.github.io/stackFrontQuestions.html)